# Django rest framework api response add-on

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So i have a table call Book. I am using modelviewset but i wanted my response to have an add on response.

**In my Book table :**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'book', 'author')
```

**view**

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

the return result after post or update method will return the data/field which user have create/update. But i wanted to add on to it for example.

**current result**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "book": "hello",
    "author": "helloauth",
}
```

**result i want**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "book": "hello",
    "author": "helloauth",
    "message": "You have successfully create a book",
    "status": "200",
}
```

The custom code i have now is just showing the message only:

**custom views**

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({"message": "You have successfully create a book",
                         "status": "200"}, headers=headers)
```

How to i make it combine/display together ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this is just add your messages in a `Response.data` dict:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(BookViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data['message'] = 'You have successfully create a book'
        response.data['status'] = '200'
        return response
```

Comment: Thank you. This has make my life easier